# Firebase crash report uploading error

Tags: ios

I am integrating firebase crash reports without cocoa pods in iOS. I am getting the error. Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Firebase Crash Reporting: Failed to transmit crash: Error Domain=com.google.FirebaseCrash Code=1 "Upload failed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Upload failed, NSLocalizedFailureReason=HTTP Error Code 400:  { URL: https://mobilecrashreporting.googleapis.com/v1/crashes:batchCreate?key=AIzaSyAmAo91FUyOLsvhIbsSo9U4bwoY9pHBDSM&alt=json } { status code: 400, headers {     "Cache-Control" = private;     "Content-Encoding" = gzip;     "Content-Length" = 123;     "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";     Date = "Mon, 13 Jun 2016 17:01:01 GMT";     Server = ESF;     Vary = "Origin, X-Origin, Referer";     "alt-svc" = "quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25\"";     "alternate-protocol" = "443:quic";     "x-content-type-options" = nosniff;     "x-frame-options" = SAMEORIGIN;     "x-xss-protection" = "1; mode=block"; } }}

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue and couldn't figure out what the reason for the 400 error was. Here is a not-too-painful way to get the reason for the error:

Install Charles Proxy (or whatever your favorite way to inspect requests is) , go to Help>SSL Proxying>Install Charles Root Certificate in iOS Simulators. Then get it to fail to send the crash report again in the simulator and look for the request to mobilecrashreporting.googleapis.com in Charles. Click on Response to view the actual response JSON, which should have the reason the request is failing.

Mine was an invalid BundleVersion value, yours will probably be something else:

`{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Invalid iOS internal version: '1A001'.",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
}`

Once I fixed the version number crash reporting started working. This info should really be in the original failure log, so I'm going to make a feature request for that. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

click the setting icon (beside Overview menu) > click Project Setting
choose Service Accounts and then click Crash Reporting
Wait for loading ….

After that, click again the setting icon (beside Overview menu) > click Permissions
choose Service accounts from the left menu
find “firebase-crashreporting” service account name > click the 3 dots on the right side to create key and choose Json format .
After that you will get the downloaded “Unknow” file and then change it’s name to “ServiceAccount.json”
Drag it to the Xcode project.

Add “Run Script” at Build Phases.
Put the following 2 lines:
GOOGLE_APP_ID=1:xxxx5xxxxxxx:ios:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx (take from GoogleService-Info.plist)
${SRCROOT}/Firebase/Crash/upload-sym ${SRCROOT}/ServiceAccount.json

FYI
No need to put “” at ${SRCROOT}
${SRCROOT}/Firebase/Crash/upload-sym  >>>>> I put upload-sym under  Firebase/Crash/